# Make every <li> take up the same amount of browser width with grids

Tags: html, css

How do I make this `ul` take up the whole width on the web page, no matter what width the window is?

http://jsfiddle.net/32hp1w5p/

```css
ul {
  grid-column: 1/13;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>ONE</a></li>
  <li><a>TWO</a></li>
  <li><a>THREE</a></li>
</ul>
```

In this jsfiddle there is three li. I'd like every li in this case take up 33% of the total width, and together they fill out the whole width of the web browser window

Comment: where is the parent displayed as a grid ? .... why display:table, float, inline-block ?

Comment: what other settings for the style for `ul` have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a typo and added margin *(makes element shrinks and centers)* aside wrong display choices:

*That's a lot mistakes and wrong approach ... welcome to the fun of CSS*, added a few comments.

```css
body {
  /* added the parent grid CSS system */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(13, 1fr);
}

ul {
  grid-column: 1 / span 13;
  /* span is: the typo / missing */
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  /* lets make it a flexbox, 
  a grid will do too , 
  so would a table at width:100% 
  if table-layout is set to fixed 
  and li displayed as table-cell */
  margin: 0;/* none or 0, but not auto */
  padding: 0;/* might be usefull here ;) */
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  /* share evenly avalaible space */
  border: 1px solid red;
}

li a {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: /*inline-*/block;/* to fill parent's width */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>ONE</a></li>
  <li><a>TWO</a></li>
  <li><a>THREE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `width: 100vw` for your `ul`, that means, that the element with this rule should take the width of the screen. If you also want to exclude the width of margins or other elements, you can use something like this: `width: calc(100vw - widthToExclude);`.

Here is a live example (I use `calc(33.3vw - 2px);`, because `li`s also have `border-left: 1px` and `border-right: 1px`):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: calc(33.3vw - 2px);
}

li a {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a>ONE</a></li>
  <li><a>TWO</a></li>
  <li><a>THREE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: display:flex on ul and flex:1 on li is plenty enough ;) http://jsfiddle.net/32hp1w5p/1/

Comment: @G-Cyr, yes, Flexbox is pretty cool and I like to use it, but the OP didn't ask about Flexbox solution and I don't know, is the Flexbox way OK for Him/Her

Comment: the thing is that you ommitted the grid CSS context . grid-column:1/13; on ul  was not properly declared in the first place i believe ;) . then the display of ul can be block/table/flex or grid again ;)

Comment: @G-Cyr, yes, and I removed this rule, because I don't see any reason to use it.